# Parsing of spark RDD using scala

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark, polygon, rdd

I have a polygon file in ^ separated format

```
(ID123^Polygon(1.0 1.0,2.1 3.4,7.2 8.8,9.1 19.2,7.3 8.8)
```

I have a case class

```
case class polygon(long:double,lat:double)
```

I want to parse the file in to the class. My file is on HDFS. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Your polygon class has two parameters. What exactly are you trying to do with that first line of data?

Comment: How exactly are you going to parse your polygon into a LatLong pair ? DO you understand that your polygon has many data points ? Please read about Polygon representation.

Comment: Polygon is a vector type GIS data. Now there are many formats of polygon data like - `GeoJSON`, `Shapefile`, `Esri TIN`, `AutoCAD DXF`, `KML` and many more. Which one is yours ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a line `(ID123^Polygon(1.0 1.0,2.1 3.4,7.2 8.8,9.1 19.2,7.3 8.8)` means that it is a polygon shape with `id = ID123` and its has five vertices `Vertex(1.0, 1.0)`,`Vertex(2.1, 3.4)`,`Vertex(7.2, 8.8)`,`Vertex(9.1, 19.2)` and `Vertex(7.3, 8.8)`.

Now you can do the following,

```
// Define your Vertex class
case class Vertex(lat: Float, long: Float)

// Define your polygon class
case class Polygon(vertices: List[Vertex])

val lines = sc.textFile("polygon_file_path")

// RDD of (id, polygon) pair
// RDD[(String, Polygon)]
val polygonsWithId = lines
  .map(l => {
    val (id :: polyStr :: Nil) = l.drop(1).dropRight(1).split('^').toList
    val polyVerticesStr = polyStr.split('(').apply(1)
    val polyVertices = polyVerticesStr.split(',')
      .toList
      .map(s => s.split(' '))
      .map(a => Vertex(a(0).toFloat, a(1).toFloat))
    val polygon = Polygon(polyVertices)

    (id, polygon)
  })
```